# UIButtons in UITableviewCell goes out of bonds in Zoomed mode display of iPhone 6+

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, ios-autolayout, iphone-6-plus

[image]

I'm using a UITableView with Custom Cell. In this custom cell there are 7 UIButtons added. All Buttons are circular in size. They are added in such a manner that a horizontal row is made. To fit UI in all devices I have used Auto Layout. UI is perfect in all devices.

But when I run this in iPhone 6+ with zoomed mode, the two UIButtons crosses the iPhone 6+ bounds i.e. in goes beyond the bounds of Iphone 6+ width. But when I use Standard mode of iPhone6+, there is no such issue. I have tried with all combinations of Autolayouts but couldn't succeed.

Comment: Would you add image(s) to this via imgur.com please, so people can see what you mean? I am not an iPhone dev, but I'd guess it might not be clear unless it is illustrated.